# Inno Setup update a installed program

Tags: file, copy, inno-setup, updates

In my into setup script I put the following line :

```
Source: "..\Source\Programmverzeichnis\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs;
```

At the first install the setup copy 20 files into the program folder. For the second compile I put 5 files into the folder ..\Source\Programmverzeichnis. Inno Setup get these 5 new files and put it into the second setup at compiling. Both setup have the same setup script. Only the 5 files are changed in the source.

If I installed the first setup and then the second setup with the new 5 files. The second setup doesn't copy the new 5 files into the program folder. The flags 'onlyifdestfileexists' and 'onlyifdoesntexist' have no effect.

What can I do, that the second setup copy the new 5 files into the program folder if I only put it into the source and make a new compile ?

Comment: Show us an install-time log file of the second setup (`/log=` command-line switch).

Comment: Also, seeing your question history, note that on Stack Overflow, you should accept the (correct) answers that you were given here.

Comment: In the setup log you don't see that any files are copied. Or any other error messages.

I want only the correct option or command, that the 5 new files are copied with the update setup if I append these files to the common setup.

Comment: We need [mcve], i.e. complete example script, compiler log and installer log.